# Issue with Angular Material width

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Angular Material `MatDialog`.

I open the corresponding `MatDialogRef` the following way:

```
   const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    ...............
    dialogConfig.width = this.commonService.positionAndSizeCropperDialogBox().dialogWidthSize.toString();
    dialogConfig.height = ........
    console.log('dialogConfig.width='+dialogConfig.width);
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CropperDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
```

The output is `dialogConfig.width=780`.

But when I inspect the `width`:

```
let dialog = document.getElementsByClassName("mat-dialog-container")[0]
console.log(width: "+dialog.offsetWidth)
```

the output is `width: 98`.

I have the same problem with the `height`.

Comment: Try use this dialogConfig.width.px=780

Comment: Hello Tomasz, I realized that I forgot the 'px' thanks to you. I am scatty. Thanks